# Spring rspec can't connect to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring, rspec

I have a new Rails 5 app. I installed the `spring` and `spring-commands-rspec` gems as specified in their directions. I can run `rspec` by itself and the tests run fine. However, if I run the Spring binstub `bin/rspec` I get this:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 227
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `initialize': could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::ConnectionBad)
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:217:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
    etc...
```

I have a Rails 4 app that uses the binstubs and `bin/rspec` works great. What gives?

Incidentally, `rake spec` fails the same way, with that database connection error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassing. I had not set up my database.yml properly to inherit settings from `*default`, so the message above literally was telling me there was no database running. Once I got that fixed, the binstub worked again.